# Getting 400_BAD_REQUEST when i'm trying to return data from django endpoint

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Currently i'm trying to make an APIView that returns data like this:

```
["question_text": "answer_text", "question_text": "answer_text"] ...
```

So, basically i want to make that in order to get the current user quizzes attempts, with the next REQUEST BODY:

```
"quizname"
```

my **UserAnswer** model looks like this:

```
class UserAnswers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer,related_name='Answer', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

**Answer** model :

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', verbose_name="Answer")
    is_right = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_checked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text
```

**Question** model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, related_name='question', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', verbose_name="Question")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

Basically, the UserAnswers table contains a FK to Answer, that contains a FK to Question, that contains a FK to quiz

I tried to do this in my APIView:

```
class UserAnswersView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self,request):
        try:
            data = request.data # quizName 
            toReturn = {}
            userAnswers = UserAnswers.objects.filter(user=request.user) # Getting all entries from UserAnswers table WHERE user = request.user
            for userEntry in userAnswers: # parsing al entries
                answer = Answer.objects.get(answer_text=userEntry.answer) # Getting the answer of every entry
                question = Question.objects.get(id=answer.question_id) # Getting the question of every entry
                quiz = Quiz.objects.get(id=question.quiz_id) # Getting the quiz of every entry
                if (quiz.category == request.data): # Checking if the current quiz is the one that we have interests in (the quiz name that is given by the request body)
                    toReturn[question.question_text] = {}
                    toReturn[question.question_text] = answer.answer_text
            return Response(toReturn,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

But i'm getting

```
Bad Request: /answers/
"GET /answers/ HTTP/1.1" 400 0
```

Does anyone know how am i supposed to return data in the format i want?

Comment: `except Exception as e` is too broad and it's wrong. you should specify the exceptions that may raises, then handle them separately. For now, add `print(e)` for getting traceback, and share that with us

Comment: Thank you so much! Apparently, ```answer = Answer.objects.get(answer_text=userEntry.answer)``` returned 3 answers instead of 1 because i filtered using the answer_text and there are multiple answers with the same text. So i changed to ```answer = Answer.objects.get(id=userEntry.answer_id)``` and now everything works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `answer = Answer.objects.get(answer_text=userEntry.answer)` returned 3 answers instead of 1 because i filtered using the answer_text and there are multiple answers with the same text.
So i changed to `answer = Answer.objects.get(id=userEntry.answer_id)` and now everything works properly.